# Finger print on php

Tags: php, image-processing

Is there a way to recognize an image or something like a fingerprint or a very complex image on  `php`?

Do you know a `library` or anything to recognize images like this?

Comment: When do say "like a fingerprint" what do you mean? A toeprint?

Comment: well you know a very complex image sorry for not especification

Comment: I think it would be easier if you explained what you're trying to do. Recognise similar images?

Comment: yes, get an image from a device, and compare it with something I already have, do I have to use any artificial intelligence technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imageMagick : [imagMagick Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

```
<?php

$image1 = new imagick("image1.png");

$image2 = new imagick("image2.png");

$result = $image1->compareImages($image2, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR);
$result[0]->setImageFormat("png");

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $result[0];

?>
```

from the php doc.

This class can do the job too :
[Comparison class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6378-PHP-Compare-two-images-to-check-if-they-are-identical.html)

Oh and for fingerprint, the comparison is basically based on a very complicated methods (comparing 12 identical areas), you can't just do it with simple php script

Comment: Does it have a tolerance of difference, like 10%, can this be a parameter?, or it has to be the same image?

Comment: This method is unlikely to give acceptable results if you're really talking about fingerprints.

Comment: i added a link to another solution